# Fetch data from database into a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've created an array of categories in php like this:

```
$cats=array("Coffee", "Beverages", "Drinks", "Snacks/Desserts");
```

But I want to make it like dynamic. Let's say when I update my database via my website (delete-change name-add a new category), I need this array to follow those updates.

Is is possible? Or else, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can indeed, just use array_push() !

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

It pushes your passed variables to the end of the Array, and it increases its size.

Answer (score 3):

No. Array can not follow your updates. But you can create the array based on database content. Which is usually what all sites do.

Comment: +1 Yup, and there probably isn't a single PHP/MySQL tutorial/book that doesn't cover that topic.